# Eleição Para Moderadores da Comunidade 2016

Tags: debate, eleição, moderadores

Começaram as Eleições para Moderadores 2016!

Temos **2 vagas** abertas e a eleição terá 3 etapas:

1. Candidatura
2. Primárias
3. Eleições

Eleições costumam durar entre duas e três semanas, mas isso varia de acordo com o número de candidatos.

Para mais detalhes, e saber como participar, visite

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election

Caso você tenha mais perguntas sobre o processo de eleição, ou para os candidatos, pergunte no meta!
Basta usar a tag [eleição](/questions/tagged/elei%c3%a7%c3%a3o).

Comment: Como o tempo passa rápido, parece que foram ontem as eleições para moderador. Que vençam os mais preparados, boa sorte aos candidatos. :D

Comment: Alguma motivação especial para as eleições? Ou é apenas porque o site cresceu e sobrecarregou os moderadores atuais e por isso decidiram arrumar mais 2 para ajudar?

Comment: @VictorStafusa apenas pq o site está crescendo. Se algum moderador fosse sair as eleições possuiriam mais vagas disponíveis, para completar 6 no total.